# React: Trouble implementing Redux with React-router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

today i'm trying to implement Redux for the first time on a react-app because it has been a mess to manage state/props, it's pretty good on the redux side so far but when i try to link my store with my app + router i run into errors.

Depending on how i place my router tags 2 things appens:

-not compiling (most of the time because i have  outside of the router)

-compiling, rendering but when i try to navigate url changes but not the components that should render.

I did many tries (a lot) so i reverted to when i just linked the store.

Below is my index.js:

```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import App from './App';
   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
   import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

   import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
   import store from './store'

   ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <BrowserRouter>
         <App />
       </BrowserRouter>
     </Provider>,
     document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

And my App.js (shorthen because it's long and messy):

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'

    // Components imports

    import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
    import store from './store'
    import { ensureAuth, login, register, updateInputAuth, logout } from         './actions/authActions'


    class App extends Component {
      //states

      //methods

      render() {
        const { pathname } = window.location
        const { logged, user, loginError, registerError, inputLogin, inputRegister, successMessage } = this.props
        return (
          <>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"         id="navbar">

              // My app navbar basically, usses <Link> tags

            </nav>
            {
              !logged ?
              <>
                <ModalConnect />
                <ModalRegister />
              </>
              : null
            }
            <>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Root}/>
                <Route path='/ground' render={(props) => <GroundAnalizer {...props} logged={this.state.logged} />} />
                <Route path='/air' component={AirAnalizer} />
                <Route path='/simulateur' render={(props) => <Simulateur         {...props} logged={logged} log={this.connect} reg={this.register}                 onInputChange={this.onInputChange} register={this.state.register} login=        {this.state.login} errors={this.state.errors} errorsLog={this.state.errorsLog}                 confirmMsg={this.state.confirmMsg} />} />
                <Route path='/calculateur-route' component={CalculateurRoute} />
                <Route path='/triangulateur' component={Triangulateur} />
              </Switch>
            </>
          </>
        )
      }
    }

    export default connect((store) => {
      return{
        logged: store.auth.logged,
        user: store.auth.user,
        loginError: store.auth.loginError,
        registerError: store.auth.registerError,
        inputLogin: store.auth.inputLogin,
        inputRegister: store.auth.inputRegister,
        successMessage: store.auth.successMessage,
      }
    })(App)
```

So there it is, what am i doing wrong and how i should add my store/routing so it does work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this document](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md).

You need to import `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` and wrap the `connect` export you have there with a call to `withRouter` in the components that use React Router navigation.

Thus, your code should be something like:

```
// Before

export default connect((store) => {
      return{
        logged: store.auth.logged,
        user: store.auth.user,
        loginError: store.auth.loginError,
        registerError: store.auth.registerError,
        inputLogin: store.auth.inputLogin,
        inputRegister: store.auth.inputRegister,
        successMessage: store.auth.successMessage,
      }
    })(App)

// After

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export default withRouter(connect((store) => {
      return{
        logged: store.auth.logged,
        user: store.auth.user,
        loginError: store.auth.loginError,
        registerError: store.auth.registerError,
        inputLogin: store.auth.inputLogin,
        inputRegister: store.auth.inputRegister,
        successMessage: store.auth.successMessage,
      }
    })(App))
```

[This link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) also has some more information on how this works.

Comment: Furthermore, I also recommend splitting the arguments passed into the `connect` call into separate variables for more clarity - note for future development

Comment: Thank you ! I just got this working :) thanks also for the recommandation i'll keep it in mind for later.

Comment: @Halt No problem.

I find it better to keep everything I can separated - for example having more but smaller components also is something I appreciate a lot, given that they can be reused later too - this is a good recommendation that I sometimes forget as well :)

The case for the variables is also one of creating your own code patterns - you will begin to expect the bottom of the file to have both a mapStateToProps and a mapActionsToProps variable (or ones with simillar names), which are then passed to the connect call, making everything cleaner by keeping everything in the same place

Comment: Yes that's what i'm looking for in the near future and i'm already doing that with react alone. Like having types of imports separated by lines or method: lifecycle in order then my own ones